# How to create a custom field on entry form with add-on

Tags: expressionengine

Currently I'm working on an extension for Expression Engine (2.9.2) and I'd like to create a custom field on the entry form in Control Panel. So far I only found that it could be created via Channel Fields in CP which is not what I want. There are currently a lot of channels, some not using the default channel field configuration, and we would have to create the fields in Channel Fields multiple times and with different short names.

I know how to create fields in the database so storing/retrieving the information is not a problem.

I've had a look at the developer documentation and the hooks section but unfortunately it's not very explanatory in these regards and doesn't give examples.

Is there a way to create custom fields on the create/edit entry form automatically by an extension?

Thanks in advance.